# 404 Error showing for Asset Images

Tags: assets, image, 404

In the backend, I could upload an image. I see it loads fine in the backend admin CP.

But it goes to a 404 error on the front end.

File System Path:
/home/devserv1/colorcomputergames.com/assets/clones/

The URL to your folder:
http://www.colorcomputergames.com/assets/clones/

The direct URL to the image is:
www.colorcomputergames.com/assets/clones/lunar_lander.png

But it brings up a 404 Error. I read here to look into the server settings. I'm running Apache.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. I assumed that my assets folder needed 744 just as the install instructions mentioned for the Craft CMS folders. But, I need to change the permissions to the standard 755. Once I did, I could view the images.

Comment: Almost four years later this helped me out. Thanks.